# Eclipse Plugin Development - Hide "Build Working Set" under Project menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I successfully removed "Build All" "Build Project" "Clear..." "Build Automatically" and "Generate Java docs" from the PROJECT Menu. I am using Activity to hide them.

---

But I am not able to remove "Build Working Set" at all.

- I can't get its ID from Plugin-In Menu Spy
- I tried to search its id in Plugin-registry. But I couldn't get anything useful.

Please help me removing this from the project menu, as this command is not needed in my perspective.

Comment: If you have "Generate Java docs" in there, you should probably first think about removing unused/unwanted dependencies. That would remove the related menu items much more reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This menu is added by the Eclipse RCP action builder `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder` in the `addWorkingSetBuildActions`:

```java
private void addWorkingSetBuildActions(MenuManager menu) {
    buildWorkingSetMenu = new MenuManager(IDEWorkbenchMessages.Workbench_buildSet);
    IContributionItem workingSetBuilds = new BuildSetMenu(window,
            getActionBarConfigurer());
    buildWorkingSetMenu.add(workingSetBuilds);
    menu.add(buildWorkingSetMenu);
}
```

Unfortunately the `MenuManager` constructor this is using doesn't specify an id, so I don't think you can use an activity to suppress it.

Comment: I guess it has to be done programatically then. Can you help me with it?